# Cross Saved search transaction by status and billed

Tags: oracle, netsuite

I want to know were I can create a transaction saved search that bring me the "Status" of all Sales Order and for sales orders "BILLED" status, show me the amount PAID in the invoice related and Amount Due.

What formula (text) can I have to use?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are certain expectations. Take a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and review [ask].  Specifically, update your question to contain table definitions (ddl) and sample date, as text - **no images** (or better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18))  and the expected results of that data.  Also post what you have tried and the results of those trials.

Answer (score 0):

In the criteria tab do this:

- Type: Invoice
- MainLine :Yes

in the results tab something like this:

[image]